# vcf file to gene annotations and or genes

Tags: vcf, gene

Is there some tool that will convert a vcf/bcf file to some gene annotation, based on the fact that I have the gene annotation of the already exsisting reference genome. Or some tool that will give me the genes based on the most probable chance.

Comment: VCF files contain information on variants. Each position in a VCF file can be attributed to a gene (if it falls within a gene), is that what you're looking for? By "gene annotation of the already existing reference genome", are you referring to a GTF/GFF file?

Comment: I believe the question is about using VEP. https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/index.html maybe?

Comment: People should really stop abusing the word "convert". Does OP wish to annotate their VCF or query a larger dataset based on some data in the VCF or do they think they can actually convert information about variants to information about genes?

Comment: I already have annotate my VCF(actually bcf file) file with SnpEff. So I sort of doubt whether it was possible to convert it to information about genes. On one hand it would be logically if it could on a biological perspective, on a technical perspective however, it wouldn't be that strange it that isn't that easy.

Comment: Yes I think I need VEP

Comment: VEP and snpEff give you similar information, as does ANNOVAR. What is the "information about genes" that you are looking for?

Comment: Like what the actual sequence is mutated and by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a FASTA file by applying variants found in a VCF file is called "creating a consensus FASTA file". You can use [`bcftools consensus`](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#consensus). Unfortunately, the tools only works genome-wide (at the FASTA level), so you might need to use a different tool to extract a gene sequence from the FASTA file using the gene's co-ordinates.

If the VCF file is annotated with HGVS notations for the variants, there might be a way to use those notations to apply the edit to the reference gene/transcript sequence directly. I know [the hgvs python module](https://hgvs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) works well with the HGVS notation, but I don't see a way to "apply" the variant to the reference sequence.